# Subdomain does not redirect with SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, subdomain

I have a domain `example.com`, which is working with a SSL certificat (letsencrypt). I want to add a subdomain `sub.example.com` to  `example.com:<port>`. 
I use my V-Server and the subdomain redirects via `proxy tp example.com:<port>`.

Now the problem: If I call `example.com:<port>`, the tomcat server is called and works. But if I call `sub.example.com`, I get the error: ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your SSL certificate does not include sub.example.com. Likely it's only for example.com. Get a wildcard certificate that supports *.example.com or a certificate for sub.example.com and serve that for those requests.

Comment: From my experience letencrypt don't support the wildcard. (could be wrong bee a few months since i made my certs). So yes, OP will have to make a cert for the subdomains. This subdomain certs will be treated as a request so make sure you don't hit you letencrypt request limit. Depending on your server configuration you have many option to do that.
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/can-i-use-letsencrypt-in-more-than-one-subdomain/16588

Comment: OK I found a solution. I redirect the subdomain to example.com:<ApachePort>. And on the server side I created a VHost, which redirects the ApachePort port with a proxy to example.com:<TomcatPort>.

Now I have the problem, that if I use a subdomain with multiple dots, it`s not getting redirected by https. 

For example:
https://sub1.example.de -->redirects to tomcats
http://sub1.example.de -->redirects to tomcats

http://sub2.sub1.example.de -->redirects to tomcats
https://sub2.sub1.example.de --> NO RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

Open Run by pressing Windows logo key and R
Type C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc in the Open: search space and press
Right-click on the hosts file and press Delete.